# How can I check if my app "silent notification" is not being displayed in Android?

Tags: android, silent-notification

In android there is an option to "**Hide silent notifications in status bar**". It is in Android settings >> Notifications

If the user has that option activated, my app is not able to display notifications (beacuse my app only displays silent notification), and of course the user blames my app for "not working". Is there a way to detect that situation and warn the user to toggle it?

Let me attach a screenshot of that option. I used the Android Emulator using Android release 12-S.

[image: Hide silent notifications in status bar]

I cannot find that option in my Xiaomi device using Android 13.
I founded it in an OPPO device running Android 13 but in a different place. In this case it was under each specific notification settings and it was activated by default (really annoying!). See screenshot for the Oppo device:
[image: Hide silent notifications in status bar Oppo]

Any idea how to know how that value is set by code? At least in the standard Android?